# Align text in the middle vertically and put divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I just want to align my text vertically relative to the picture and put all the content inline instead of block-like. I've been using fixed position and margin-top to achieve that but it is very bad method, I think there should be way better.

Since jsFiddle is down here is some other similar site with my code.

http://www.cssdesk.com/muEnL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set child divs to display as cells. Then use vertical align attribute.

http://www.cssdesk.com/zCGrb

```
.user-container div { display: table-cell; padding: 5px; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Cool site btw. I like that it shows the css changes as you go.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want, as far as I can tell. As long as you don't wrap everything in divs, images and text/links will remain inline.

```
<div class="user-container">
    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ec39c767ba245c2434ad2c31a3c481e5?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" width="33" height="33"/>

    <a href="#">John Doe</a>

    <a href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
```

So you just need to add "vertical-align: middle" to your image style, like:

```
.user-container img {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Another option, using your original HTML, is to use this CSS:

```
.user-container div {
   display: inline;
 }

.image img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I was just about to post this. This is the best way IMO. You get rid of unnecessary markup and it does the job just fine/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. This will have the image and the name together on the same line centered vertically with the logout appearing below it (which can, of course, be adjusted):

```
.image {
  float:left;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.name {
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.logout {
  clear: both; 
}
```